# Mutate one df based on the sum of a column in another df matching criteria

Tags: r, mutate

I have `df1` that looks like this:

| state | zip code | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NC | 00001 | person |
| NC | 00001 | property |
| NC | 00000 | person |
| NC | 00001 | property |

And I want to create `df2` where each zip code is a single observation, with columns counting the number of times each 'type' appears across each zip code from `df1`:

| zip code | person | property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000 | 250 | 45 |
| 00001 | 115 | 150 |

I created `df2` so far which is a list of all unique zip codes, and tried the following method, which resulted in the column 'person' being added but every value is the same number, being the sum of each row where "person" appears across the entire dataset of `df1`.

```
df2 <- mutate(df2, person = sum(df1$type == "person"))
```

The end goal is to use a for loop to create multiple additional columns for each "type". I tried the previous method as well as the following method:

```
for(i in nrow(df2)){
df2 <- mutate(df2, person = sum(df1[i,"type"] == "person"))
}
```

But now, I get the column added with zeroes for every row.

Am I going about this the right way? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::count` followed by `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(zip_code, type) %>%
  count() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = n)
```

Output:

```
  zip_code person property
     <int>  <int>    <int>
1    12345      1        2
2    54321      1       NA
```

Data (note I changed your zip codes just for ease of identification)

```
df <- read.table(text = "state  zip_code    type
NC  12345   person
NC  12345   property
NC  54321   person
NC  12345   property", h = TRUE)
```